# How to pass a XSLT variable to a JS function?

Tags: javascript, variables, xslt

I need to pass a XSLT variable to a JS script but am not managing to do this.
This is what I have:

```
<xsl:variable name="slidename">
<xsl:value-of select="PictureID"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Then I tried:

```
<script>processSlide({$slidename});</script>
<script>processSlide({slidename});</script>
<script>processSlide($slidename);</script>
```

But no one of the three ways worked.

Normally the sintaxe {$slidename} would work into HTML like **onclick="processSlide({$slidename});"** but doing it within the < script > tag is not working.

Any idea on how to workaround it?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I just figured it out. In case of someone else needs it:

```
<script>processSlide(<xsl:value-of select="$slidename" />);</script>
```

Comment: Using an XSLT 3 processor like Saxon 9.8 or later, Saxon JS 2 or Altova the syntax `<script>processSlide({slidename});</script>` does work as long as the XSLT declares `expand-text="yes"` on the XSLT root element or on the XSLT container instruction of the `script` result element. You can even use `<script xsl:expand-text="yes">processSlide({slidename});</script>` if you can't or don't want to declare text value template expansion higher up the tree.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to add quotes: `<script>processSlide("{$slidename}");</script>`?